# Update rows of dataframe according to the content of a map

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have this dataframe :

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|brand |Timestamp |Weight     |
+------+----------+-----------+
|BR1   |1632899456|4.0        |
|BR1   |1632901256|4.0        |
|BR300 |1632901796|2.0        | 
|BR300 |1632899155|2.0        |
|BR200 |1632899155|2.0        |
```

And this map :

```
val map : Map[String, Double] = ("BR1" -> 70.0, "BR300" -> 90.0 )
```

I would like to update the column "Weight" according to the content in the map.

The purpose is to sum the value in the row with the value in the map.

The output should look like this :

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|brand |Timestamp |Weight     |
+------+----------+-----------+
|BR1   |1632899456|74.0       |
|BR1   |1632901256|74.0       |
|BR300 |1632901796|92.0       | 
|BR300 |1632899155|92.0       |
|BR200 |1632899155|2.0        |
```

I am using Spark version 3.0.2 and SQLContext, with scala language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UDF` to get the value from the map then do sum with  column value.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._


val df = Seq(("BR1", 1632901256, 4.0),
("BR300", 1632901796, 2.0),
("BR200", 1632899155, 2.0)).toDF("brand", "Timestamp", "Weight")

val map: Map[String, Double] = Map("BR1" -> 70.0, "BR300" -> 90.0)

val broadcastedMap = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(map)

val getvalueFromMap = udf((s: String) => broadcastedMap.value.getOrElse(s, 0.0))

df.withColumn("Weight", getvalueFromMap('brand) + 'Weight).show()

 /*
+-----+----------+------+
|brand| Timestamp|Weight|
+-----+----------+------+
|  BR1|1632901256|  74.0|
|BR300|1632901796|  92.0|
|BR200|1632899155|   2.0|
+-----+----------+------+*/
```

Comment: I would possibly broadcast the variable rather than using a In House map

Comment: I used the original map (not the broadcasted one) and it worked ! Is it better to broadcast the variable ?

Answer (score 2):

The map can be translated into an SQL statement. This avoids using an UDF and therefore might improve performance.

```scala
val df = ...
val map : Map[String, Double] = Map("BR1" -> 70.0, "BR300" -> 90.0 )

val sql=map.foldLeft("Weight + case brand ")((a, b) => s"$a when '${b._1}' then ${b._2}") + " else 0.0 end"
df.withColumn("Weight", expr(sql)).show()
```

The generated `sql` string is

```sql
Weight + case brand  when 'BR1' then 70.0 when 'BR300' then 90.0 else 0.0 end
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+------+
|brand| Timestamp|Weight|
+-----+----------+------+
|  BR1|1632899456|  74.0|
|  BR1|1632901256|  74.0|
|BR300|1632901796|  92.0|
|BR300|1632899155|  92.0|
|BR200|1632899155|   2.0|
+-----+----------+------+
```